# Not able to configure Jenkins to deploy a spring boot application on cloud foundry

Tags: jenkins, spring-boot, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a `Spring Boot` application that exposes a `REST` api (`http://localhost:8080/hello-world-rest-demo/api/hello`) and prints `Hello World` string.

I have successfully deployed this application on both local and remote `Tomcat` through `Jenkins` and it is working fine without any issues. I have also deployed it to my `Cloud Foundry` account using `cf push` command through `CLI` after creating the `manifest.yml` file successfully and is working a expected (`https://hello-world-rest-demo.cfapps.io/api/hello` returns `200` status code and prints `Hello World`).

However, the problem is that my `Jenkins` integration with `Cloud Foundry` is not working as expected and I am not able to deploy it through `Jenkins` (running on a separate physical machine which does not have `Cloud Foundry` `CLI` installed).

Not sure what am I missing here.

[image]

**manifest.yml**

```
---
applications:
- name: hello-world-rest-demo
  path: target/hello-world-rest-demo.war
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give Cloud Foundry API Endpoint for Target. For Pivotal Web Services, API Endpoint is `https://api.run.pivotal.io`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

Changed the target url to: `https://api.run.pivotal.io`